# Regarding equivalent definitions of Euclidean Submanifolds in Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine's book Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential

In the book *Riemannian Geometry* by Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine, a proposition which characterises equivalent definitions of submanifolds is given as follows:

> 1.3 **Proposition** *The following are equivalent:*
>
> i) $M$ *is a* $C^p$ *submanifold of dimension* $n$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.
>
> ii) *For any $x$ in $M$, there exist open neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ respectively, and a $C^p$ diffeomorphism $f : U\to V$ such that $f(U \cap M)=V \cap (R^n \times \{0\})$*.
>
> iii) *For any $x$ in $M$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, a neighbourhood $\Omega$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a $C^p$ map $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ such that $( \Omega, g)$ is a local parametrization of $M \cap U$ around $x$  (that is $g$ is an homeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto $M \cap U$ and $g'(0)$ is injective).*

I am trying to show that iii) implies ii) and I think that I am nearly there except I am having trouble with the following detail. I will first summarise my problem and then fill in the details.

In brief, my main problem in going from iii) to ii) is that to make my proof work I seemed to also require that $g(0)=x$. (Whereas in contrast the authors have just required that $g$ is an homeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto $M \cap U$ and $g'(0)$ is injective).

The details of what I attempted are as follows:

> **(Attempted) Proof that iii) $\implies$ ii).**
>
> Fix $x \in M$ and let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ satisfy the conditions of iii). Therefore we have a neighbourhood $W$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, a neighbourhood $\Omega$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a $C^p$ map $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ such that $g$ is an homeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto $M \cap W$ and $g'(0)$ is injective.
>
> Since the Jacobian matrix $g'(0)$ or $Dg$(at $0$), which has $n+k$ rows and $n$ columns, is injective 
>   (in this case rank $n$), that means that all of its $n$ columns are linearly independent. Therefore we could 'complete' or 'fill out' this matrix up to a full square matrix which has rank $n+k$ (i.e. nonsingular). The filled out matrix is:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_2} & \dots \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_n} & a_{11} & \dots  & a_{1k} \\
> \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_n} & a_{21} & \dots  & a_{2k} \\
> \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_2} & \dots \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_n} & a_{31} & \dots  & a_{3k} \\
>    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
> \frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_2} & \dots \frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_n} & a_{n1} & \dots  & a_{nk} \\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
> \frac{\partial g_{n+k}}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_{n+k}}{\partial x_2} & \dots \frac{\partial g_{n+k}}{\partial x_n} & a_{(n+k)1} & \dots  & a_{(n+k)k}
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> With this in mind we can define a new function $h : \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ by:
>
> $h_1=g_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) + a_{11} x_{n+1} + a_{12} x_{n+2} + ... + a_{1k} x_{n+k}$ etc.
>
> Then $Dh$ at $0$ is just the matrix above. Therefore, by the inverse function theorem, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ such that $h$ carries $V$ in a one to one fashion onto an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ and we can guarantee that $h(0)$ (which is equal to $g(0)$) is in $U$.

This is where I think my problem arises. Although the original $W$ contained $x$, I can't seem to guarantee that $U$ contains $x$ because the whole process to show that $U$ exists has relied upon the inverse function theorem, which could return a smaller open set than $W$.

Therefore I am not certain I am on the correct track, but apart from this little detail, if I could assume that $g(0)=x$, I think this would all work.

Help would be much appreciated as I am attempting to self-learn with no mathematical contacts at the moment.

Comment: They forgot to put $g(0)=x$ but it is requiered !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one requires in (ii)  that $f(x) = 0$ and in (iii) that $g(0) = x$. However, one can also omit these requirements, but in that case it is in my opinion misleading to require that $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ and that $\Omega$ is a neigbborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$. In fact, this is completely irrelevant unless *we want to have for some reason* that $f(x) = 0$ and $g(0) = x$.

Let us consider (ii) and (iii) as they are.

In (ii) we know that $f(x) \in \mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$, but we do not know that $f(x) = 0$. Whether $0 \in V$ is completely irrelavant. If we want to have that, we can make a translation on $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ to achieve it: The map $T_{-f(x)}: \mathbb R^{n+k} \to \mathbb R^{n+k}, T_{-f(x)}(y) = y - f(x)$ is a diffeomorphism and $f ' : U \stackrel{f}{\to} V \stackrel{T_{-f(x)}}{\to} T_{-f(x)}(V)$ has all desired properties.

The situation in (iii) is similar.

This means that you may assume that $f(x) = 0$ and $g(0) = x$ which makes your proof work.

**Edited:**

I have to make a correction: (iii) is not similar. I thought that a local parametrization of $M∩U$ around $x$ should have $g'(y)$ injective for all $y \in  \Omega$, but this is not required. In fact we need that $g'(g^{-1}(x))$ is injective, otherwise the given assumptions have no chance to assure the existence of a (small) neighborhood of $g^{-1}(x)$ which is mapped diffeomorphically onto a (small) neighborhood of $x$ in $M \cap U$. But again, if we assume $g'(g^{-1}(x)) \ne 0$, then a translation allows to assume w.l.o.g. $g^{-1}(x) = 0$.

Comment: I thought exactly that it seemed very arbitrary in ii) that $0 \in V$ when a translation as noted above can be performed. I could definitely see that this could be omitted. I am still unsure, that the $g(0)=x$ requirement can be omitted because they have specified the injectivity of $Dg$ at $0$. It seemed to me that one needs the injectivity of the Jacobian of $g$ at the same place. So far I can only see that the $g(0)=x$ could be omitted if the injectivity requirement on $Dg$ was more widespread.

Comment: @NathanC You are right, I didn't read carefully. I thought that a local parametrization of $M∩U$ around $x$ should have $g' \ne 0$ *everywhere*, but this is not required. In fact we need that $g'(g^{-1}(x)) \ne 0$, otherwise the given assumptions have no chance to assure the existence of a (small) neighborhood of $g^{-1}(x)$ which is mapped diffeomorphically onto a (small) neighborhood of $x$. But again, if we assume $g'(g^{-1}(x)) \ne 0$, then a translation allows to assume w.l.o.g. $g^{-1}(x) = 0$.

Comment: Does the **definition** of a local parametrization $g$ of $M∩U$ around $x$ in the book perhaps include that $g(0) = x$?

Comment: Oh I see , that must have been what they meant. When they added the clarification in brackets I took this to mean that the contents of the brackets were the entire content of their specification. I think the bracketed section probably just refers to 'local parametrization' and the phrase 'around x' must have included the $g(0)=x$. Thanks.